# Is there a way I can present a string to a method with the string depending on an if?

Tags: c#

I have this code where AddDefSpan is an extension method that takes a single string as a parameter.  Here I am using this:

```
        FormattedString s = new FormattedString()
            .AddDefSpan("On the ")
            .AddTabSpan("settings")
            .AddDefSpan(" screen you set ")
            .AddDtlSpan("card appearance visibility")
            .AddDefSpan(" to ")
            .AddDtlSpan("favorites")
            .AddDefSpan(" to ");
        if (App.phraseInfo.Favorite == 0)
            s.AddDefSpan(" aaa.");
        else
            s.AddDefSpan(" bbb.");
```

What I would like to know is if there is some way that I can incorporate the decision (App.phraseInfo.Favorite == 0) into the single parameter of .AddDefSpan

something like this:

```
        s.AddDefSpan(
            if (App.phraseInfo.Favorite == 0) " aaa." else " bbb."
        );
```

I realize what I just wrote is not going to work but I am wondering if there is a way that it can be made to work?

Comment: `s.AddDefSpan(App.phraseInfo.Favorite == 0 ? " aaa." : " bbb. ");`

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.  Can you advise. Should I keep the question and wait for a formal answer or delete the question. Not sure which to do.

Comment: Well you have formal answer already and user even got 5 upvotes, so deleting it will hurt him :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [the `?:` conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
s.AddDefSpan(App.phraseInfo.Favorite == 0 ? " aaa." : " bbb.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional or ternary operator which is present in most programming languages. (ternary as it takes 3 operands)

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

If `condition` evaluates to true, then `first_expression` is evaluated and its result returned, otherwise the `second_expression` is evaluated and returned.

So in your case,

```
s.AddDefSpan(App.phraseInfo.Favorite == 0 ? " aaa." : " bbb. ");
```